# Render only children in $_menu

Tags: category, navigation, category-tree

i.e.

I have the following category: main category (!= root)

```
Main category
|
|- sub category 1
|
|- sub category 2
|
|- sub category 3
```

My navigation,

```
  <ul>
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
  </ul>
```

Now renders

```
Main category
```

How can I get it to render just the sub categories, like

```
Subcategory 1
Subcategory 2
Subcategory 3
```

(The reason I put all my categories in one main is to be able to link to mysite.com/shop for all products. Main category therefore is /shop )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably do that by overwriting the file `app/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php`

**app/code/local/YourCompany/Catalog/etc/config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_Catalog>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </YourCompany_Catalog>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <catalog>
                <rewrite>
                  <navigation>YourCompany_Catalog_Block_Navigation</navigation>
               </rewrite>
           </catalog>
       </blocks>       
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/YourCompany/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php:**

```
class YourCompany_Catalog_Block_Navigation extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation {
    public function renderCategoriesMenuHtml($level = 0, $outermostItemClass = '', $childrenWrapClass = '')
{
    $activeCategories = array();
    foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $child) {
        if ($child->getIsActive()) {
            $activeCategories[] = $child;
        }
    }

    $activeCategoriesCount = count($activeCategories);
    $hasActiveCategoriesCount = ($activeCategoriesCount > 0);

    if (!$hasActiveCategoriesCount) {
        return '';
    }

    $html = '';
    $j = 0;
    foreach ($activeCategories as $category) {
        foreach ($category->getChildren() as $child) { // Added this loop to bypass the first top categories
            $html .= $this->_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml(
                $child,
                $level,
                ($j == $activeCategoriesCount - 1),
                ($j == 0),
                true,
                $outermostItemClass,
                $childrenWrapClass,
                true
            );
            $j++;
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
}
```

**app/etc/modules/YourCompany.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <YourCompany_Catalog>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </YourCompany_Catalog>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Global overview of the files to creates:**
    app
        code
            local
                YourCompany
                    Catalog
                        Block
                            Navigation.php
                        etc
                            config.xml
        etc
            modules
                YourCompany_Catalog.xml

Comment: Are there any additional steps? Nothing happens... And I also guess you mean app > code > local ?

Comment: Yes in app/code/local, my answer has been edited by someone else with this error. You also have to declare your new local module (I've edited my answer)

Comment: Hm still nothing. I've also refreshed my cache. I'm also sure I copy pasted everything in the right directory, as well as a find & replace for YourCompany edit: and I also had config.xml already capitalized

Comment: I might found  what I'm doing wrong. My menu is located @ page/html/topmenu.phtml (instead of /Catalog/ as your answer suggests (I guess). I guess that changes your answer?

Comment: It is weird that nothing happened. 
The phtml file is not where your menu is created. It defines the custom elements of your menu but the "classic" menu creation with the categories is in the navigation.php file.
My answer wasn't quite right, but I tried it today and the following works.

Comment: Hm I guess I'm doing something wrong elsewhere then. I'll accept it as an answer because it should work for others :)

Comment: Could you please double check that you've replaced every "YourCompany" by the right folder name ? and that you've created the files according to the files hierarchy I've added to my post (it is important to respect the first capital letter when I've put one as well) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22271/discussion-between-christophe-and-frank).